# Getting AeroMexico to honor vouchers

Tags: vouchers, aeromexico

I have two vouchers from AM, each good for a roundtrip flight to or from Mexico City. They expire March 1. AeroMexico says they can be redeemed by email or through an agent (there is no way to redeem them on the website or by phone). Last week I finally got the agent to make a reservation. I had 12 hours to pay the taxes. The person at the phone number listed said he couldn't process the payment, the office listed at 34th in Manhattan is now a travel agency, and of course when I emailed payment info to the agent who made the reservation, she did not respond (typically takes 1 - 4 days, doesn't work weekends). A few days earlier I even went out to JFK and waited several hours for some of their staff to come on shift, only to be told this can only be done by email. Basically, AeroMexico's vouchers seem like a scam. I am at wit's end.

What can I do to get them to honor the vouchers? I have been extremely flexible with dates, so that is not the issue.

Do I stand any chance of suing them in small claims in NY (given that they have an office at JFK)?

Comment: Follow up. After filing the n-th complaint and sending the n-th email, the agent I had corresponded with finally called me and we completed the reservation. Why she didn't do this two weeks ago when I asked her, I have no idea. She also told me, contrary to what was written on the automated email, that the booked ticket did not expire after 12 hours. So...if offered an AeroMexico voucher, think twice. If redeeming an AM voucher, prepare to spend many hours and several weeks fighting with them. Note, too, that I write and speak fluent Spanish. They are probably impossible to deal with in Eng.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't over complicate this.  Redeeming vouchers is a common occurrence.

Most often, the easiest thing to do is make a reservation (reserve only, don't pay) on the airlines website, then call directly to redeem the vouchers.

They will tell you exactly what to do with the vouchers and take payment for any remaining balance.

You don't need an agent or to visit an airport.

Comment: Apparently you have never tried to redeem AeroMexico vouchers. There is no way to do it on the website, nor any way to call them (at least for these). Hence my question.

Comment: @zadrozny I didn't say to redeem them on the web site, few airlines do.  Their reservations line is right on the web site.